# How to call a function in a function in python

Tags: python, function, nested

I have a problem about function in python, and i'm pretty new in programming, so please giving your examples in the simplest way, thanks

I want to call a function in a function like this:

```
def func1 (a):
    b = a + 1
    def func2():
       c = b*3
       print c
    def func3():
       c = b/5
       print c

func1(5).func2()
```

how can i call func2 inside func1 or func3 inside func1 ? and yes, i do need func1, func2 and func3, i don't want to use class

Comment: The same way you call any other function... `func2()` and `func3()` after they are defined...

Comment: Did you try just calling them? Although I can't see why you'd want to do this.

Comment: just call it ? .....

Comment: You cannot do `func1(5).func2()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to call it ?
And TIPs : Remember about indent

```
def func1 (a):
    b = a + 1
    def func2():
       c = b*3
       print c
    def func3():
       c = b/5
       print c
    funct2()  #function called , WORKS !
```

Comment: yep, **b** will be visible for both functions just like in JS are scopes working.

Comment: @MinhHiếuĐào No you __cannot__ do `func1().func2()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1 (a):
    b = a + 1
    def func2():
       c = b*3
       print c
    def func3():
       c = b/5
       print c
    return func2,func3
```

**Closure may works**

Comment: so can i do this :   func1(5).func2 ??

Comment: first of all funct1 return packed two functions (in tuple) so You wouldn't be able to call this function like this.

Comment: joke  @Take_Care_ 1

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't really need new functions to do such simple tasks, calling functions in another function would be something like this:

```
def func2(b):
    return b*3

def func3(b):
    return b/5

def func1(a):
    b = a + 1
    c = func2(b)
    print c
    c = func3(b)
    print c
```

and finally call your function with an input, 5 for example:

```
func1(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve the syntax you want but it is **highly irregular** and I would **strongly** advise against using it. It is hacky.

```
def func1(a):
    b = a + 1
    def func2():
       c = b*3
       print c
    def func3():
       c = b/5
       print c
    func1.func2 = func2
    func1.func3 = func3
    return func1
```

Now, inside the interpreter shell:

```
>>> def func1(a):
...     b = a + 1
...     def func2():
...        c = b*3
...        print c
...     def func3():
...        c = b/5
...        print c
...     func1.func2 = func2
...     func1.func3 = func3
...     return func1
... 
>>> func1(5).func2()
18
>>>
```

Please, for Guido, do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

The function objects `func2` and `func3` are local to the function `func1`, which means they do not exist outside of `func1` unless `func1` explicitly returns them to the calling environment.

So if you want to call those functions *outside* of `func1` (as your posted code attempts to do) you need to do something like this:

```
def func1(a):
    b = a + 1
    def func2():
       c = b*3
       print c
    def func3():
       c = b/5
       print c
    return func2, func3

f2, f3 = func1(5.0)
f2()
f3()
```

**output**

```
18.0
1.2
```

`f2` and `f3` will use the value of the `a` parameter that was given to `func1` when they were created. If you want to use a different `a` then simply call `func1` again; each time you call it new instances of the  `func2` and `func3` function objects are created.

---

*Aside*

Note that I passed an argument of `5.0` rather than `5` to `func1`. That's to ensure that `b/5` in `func3` uses float division. That's not necessary in Python 3, and to get the Python 3 behaviour in Python 2 you can put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you very much